# Searching through html in scrapy?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, tags

Is it possible to use a for loop to search through the text of tags that correspond to a certain phrase. I've been trying to create this loop but isn't hasn't been working. Any  help is appreciated thanks! Here is my code:

```
    def parse_page(self, response):
        titles2 = response.xpath('//div[@id = "mainColumn"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
        year =  response.xpath('//div[@id = "mainColumn"]/h1/span/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        aud = response.xpath('//div[@id="scorePanel"]/div[2]')
        a_score = aud.xpath('./div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/text()').extract()
        a_count = aud.xpath('./div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()
        c_score = response.xpath('//a[@id = "tomato_meter_link"]/span/span[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        c_count = response.xpath('//div[@id = "scoreStats"]/div[3]/span[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        info = response.xpath('//div[@class="panel-body content_body"]/ul')
        mp_rating = info.xpath('./li[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        genre = info.xpath('./li[2]/div[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
        date = info.xpath('./li[5]/div[2]/time/text()').extract_first()
        box = response.xpath('//section[@class = "panel panel-rt panel-box "]/div')
        actor1 = box.xpath('./div/div[1]/div/a/span/text()').extract()
        actor2 = box.xpath('./div/div[2]/div/a/span/text()').extract()
        actor3 = box.xpath('./div/div[3]/div/a/span/text()').extract_first()

        for x in info.xpath('//li'):
            if info.xpath("./li[x]/div[1][contains(text(), 'Box Office: ')/text()]]
                box_office = info.xpath('./li[x]/div[2]/text()')
            else if info.xpath('./li[x]/div[1]/text()').extract[0] == "Runtime: "):
                runtime = info.xpath('./li[x]/div[2]/time/text()')
```

Comment: Yes.  But what is your real question?  What have you tried?  What is your input and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is completely wrong:
1. You're using `info.` but searching from the root

```
for x in info.xpath('.//li'):
```

2. `x` is a HTML node element and you can use it this way:

```
if x.xpath("./div[1][contains(., 'Box Office: ')]"):
    box_office = x.xpath('./div[2]/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: when I try using the if statement I get the error: "name 'x' is not defined"

Comment: @user9343592 You need to use it **inside** your loop

Comment: @user9343592 I don't know but I can help if you show me your HTML

Comment: i got it to work using the x.xpath (..).extract_first() == "Runtime: ". thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need **re()** or **re_first()** to match the certain phrase.

For example:

```
            elif info.xpath('./li[x]/div[1]/text()').re_first('Runtime:') == "Runtime: "):
            runtime = info.xpath('./li[x]/div[2]/time/text()')
```

And you need to modify your for loop, cuz the variable x in it is actually a Selector but not a number, so it's not right to use it like this: li[x].

gangabass in the last answer made a good point on this.